# Ambiguous CFG to Unambiguous CFG Transformation

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm having a hard time converting this ambiguous CFG into an unambiguous one.

$S \rightarrow Sb \;  \mid\; aaSb \;\mid \; b$

If I understood correctly, the language this CFG generates is composed of either:

- a single $b$, or
- at least two $b$'s  preceded by an even number of $a$'s.

Can you help me disambiguate the CFG?

Comment: Why is the CFG ambiguous?

Comment: @mrp Different leftmost derivations can give same result, e.g.
`1) S → Sb → aaSbb → aabbb
2) S → aaSb → aaSbb → aabbb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should do the trick.

$$S \rightarrow aaSb \mid X$$
$$X \rightarrow Xb \mid b$$

The idea is that once you pick $X$, you can no longer add $a$'s to the front, so the only way to produce $aabbb$ is
$$S \rightarrow aaSb \rightarrow aaXb \rightarrow aaXbb \rightarrow aabbb$$

Comment: As simple as that... Thank you for your time @mrp